# Array push operation in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have tried to construct an array of objects. The first object pushed to array is OK. But when I tried to push the second object to the array, the first object is gone, and I got two copies of the second object in the array.

Could anyone help me understand why?

Here is the steps I did: 
$ node -v
v8.9.3

```
> let taxes = [];
undefined
> taxes
[]
> let tax = {}
undefined
> tax
{}
> tax.name='pst';
'pst'
> tax.rate = 0.07;
0.07
> tax.amount = 10.5;
10.5
> tax
{ name: 'pst', rate: 0.07, amount: 10.5 }
> taxes.push(tax);
1
> taxes
[ { name: 'pst', rate: 0.07, amount: 10.5 } ]
> tax.name='gst';
'gst'
> tax.rate = 0.05;
0.05
> tax.amount = 7.5;
7.5
> tax
{ name: 'gst', rate: 0.05, amount: 7.5 }
> taxes
[ { name: 'gst', rate: 0.05, amount: 7.5 } ]
> texes.push(tax);
2
> taxes
[ { name: 'gst', rate: 0.05, amount: 7.5 },
  { name: 'gst', rate: 0.05, amount: 7.5 } ]
> tax
{ name: 'gst', rate: 0.05, amount: 7.5 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Richard Xu

Comment: *"when I tried to push the second object"* -- there is no second object. You forgot create a second object (`tax = {}`) before setting its properties.

Comment: i dont know if it is relevant but you made typo... u texes.push and array is taxes

Answer (score 0):

The reason why taxes[0] and taxes[1] are the same is because both object is **reference** to tax object. So if you change taxes[0] or taxes[1] or tax object, they will all have the same value.

I can see you're doing this in node REPL so if you want, you can use Object.assign function. With this function you can copy properties and it's value of another object with a new reference. If you change value in tax, it won't affect the other objects.

```
taxes.push(Object.assign({}, tax));
```

Comment: No problem @RichardXu :) It helps to upvote/mark my answer as the answer to your problem. Thank you.

Comment: I did it, but it seems I don't have enough reputation. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

actually when you define tax as an object, and you assign some values to it then you push to array taxes, and later you assign another values for tax, you will lose the first values, because objects called by reference, means you overwrite on the same address in the memory: 
try this way:

Comment: you should add your example for This way

Answer (score 0):

```
>taxes.push(
>{ name: 'pst', rate: 0.07, amount: 10.5 } 
>);
>taxes.push(
>{ name: 'gst', rate: 0.05, amount: 7.5 } 
>);
```

Answer (score -1):

A new (cloned) instance of `tax` is NOT pushed into taxes array, so when modifying the tax in the same scope, the pushed object still holds the reference and once you modify the `tax` variable it affects the data in the array.